# iPhone Gdata-client Youtube query doesn't work

Tags: iphone, youtube, gdata

I'm playing with the object-c API (Gdata) of google to interact with youtube (in my case) but i'm running into a problem. I'm trying to search a youtube video with the query class:

```
NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForFeedID:nil];
    GDataQueryYouTube *query = [GDataQueryYouTube youTubeQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];


    [query setVideoQuery:@"\"Fred Flintstone\""];

    ticket = [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                               delegate:self
                      didFinishSelector:@selector(entryListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:)];


    [ticket setShouldFollowNextLinks:NO];
```

But when i execute it i have this error in the consol (the call back entryListFetchTicket is not even called)

> 2011-03-07 13:48:35.625
>   samsungTV[23061:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[NSInvocation
>   invocationWithMethodSignature:]:
>   method signature argument cannot be
>   nil'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x011ddbe9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x013325c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>     2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0114db09 +[NSInvocation
>   invocationWithMethodSignature:] + 553
>     3   samsungTV
>
>   0x00018d34 +[GDataServiceBase
>   invokeCallback:target:ticket:object:error:]
>   + 83  4   samsungTV                           0x000184a5 -[GDataServiceBase
>   handleParsedObjectForFetcher:] + 840
>     5   Foundation
>
>   0x003709a6 __NSThreadPerformPerform +
>   251   6   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x011bf01f
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  7   CoreFoundation                      0x0111d28b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
>     8   CoreFoundation
>   0x0111c786 __CFRunLoopRun + 470   9
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x0111c240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     10  CoreFoundation
>   0x0111c161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    11
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x018f9268 GSEventRunModal + 217  12 
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x018f932d GSEventRun + 115   13  UIKit
>   0x0060042e UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     14  samsungTV
>   0x00002964 main + 102     15  samsungTV
>   0x000028f5 start + 53 ) terminate
>   called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException' Program received signal:
>   “SIGABRT”.

I have no idea why...

But in the othr hand if i uses feed it works...

```
NSURL *feedURL;
    feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForFeedID:kGDataYouTubeFeedIDMostPopular];


    ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                              delegate:self
                     didFinishSelector:@selector(entryListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];


    [ticket setShouldFollowNextLinks:NO]
```

Can somebdoy give me a hand ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually define a method `entryListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:` in your class that you are using as the delegate object?

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks for GData fetches have three parameters, not two. The first code snippet is missing the error: at the end of the selector.

Be sure to define DEBUG=1 for your debug builds; the library will catch such issues.